# Objects passing objects

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to python and am currently trying to use an old module to output graphs. The code below is a excerpt from the module that uses rpy to design 
standard celeration charts (don't look it up).

I'm having trouble understanding how the class Element and class Vector work together.

I've been trying to pass the a element object to the vector get_elements but I'm not sure if that's what I should be doing.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
class Element(object):
   """Base class for Chartshare vector elements."""
   def __init__(self, offset=0, value=0):
       self.offset=offset
       self.value=value
       self.text=''

   def setText(self, value):
       self.value=value

   def getText(self):
       return self.value

   text = property(getText, setText)

class Vector(object):
   """Base class for Chartshare Vectors."""
   def __init__(self, name='', color='black', linetype='o', symbol=1, clutter=0, start=0, end=140, continuous=False, debug=False):
       self.name=name
       self.color=color
       self.linetype=linetype
       self.symbol=symbol
       self.start=start
       self.end=end
       self.elements={}
       self.debug=debug
       self.continuous=continuous

       if not self.continuous:             
           for i in range(self.start, self.end+1):
               self.elements[i]='NaN'

   def getSymbol(self):
       return self._symbol

   def setSymbol(self, value):
       if (type(value) == int):
           if (value >= 0) and (value <= 18):
               self._symbol = value
           else:
               raise SymbolOutOfRange, "Symbol should be an integer between 0 and 18."
       elif (type(value) == str):
           try:
               self._symbol = value[0]
           except IndexError:
               self._symbol=1
       else:
           self._symbol = 1    

   symbol = property(getSymbol, setSymbol)


   def getLinetype(self):
       return self._linetype

   def setLinetype(self, value):
       if (value == 'p') or (value == 'o') or (value == 'l'):
           self._linetype = value
       else:
           raise InvalidLinetype, "Line type should be 'o', 'p', or 'l'"

   linetype = property(getLinetype, setLinetype)

   def get_elements(self):
       """Returns a list with the elements of a Vector."""
       retval = []
       for i in range(self.start, self.end+1):
           if (not self.continuous):
               retval.append(self.elements[i])
           else:
               if (self.elements[i] != 'NaN'):
                   retval.append(self.elements[i])
       return retval

   def get_offsets(self):
       """Returns a list of the offsets of a Vector."""
       retval = [] 
       for i in range(self.start, self.end+1):
           if (not self.continuous):
               retval.append(i)
           else:
               if (self.elements[i] == 'NaN'):
                   retval.append(i)
       return retval

   def to_xml(self, container=False):
       """Returns an xml representation of the Vector."""
       if (container == False):
           container = StringIO.StringIO()
       xml = XMLGenerator(container)
       attrs = {}
       attrs[u'name'] = u"%s" % self.name
       attrs[u'symbol'] = u"%s" % self.symbol
       attrs[u'linetype'] = u"%s" % self.linetype
       attrs[u'color'] = u"%s" % self.color
       xml.startElement(u'vector', attrs)
       for i in range(self.start, self.end+1):
           if (self.elements[i] != 'NaN'):
               attrs.clear()
               attrs[u'offset'] = u"%s" % i
               xml.startElement(u'element', attrs)
               xml.characters(u"%s" % self.elements[i])
               xml.endElement(u'element')
       xml.endElement(u'vector')

   def render(self):
       """Plots the current vector."""
       if (self.debug):
           print "Rendering Vector: %s" % self.name
           print self.elements

       r.points(x=range(self.start, self.end+1),
                y=self.elements,
                col=self.color,
                type=self.linetype,
                pch=self.symbol)
       if (self.debug):
           print "Finished rendering Vector: %s" % self.name
```

Comment: You don't pass an `Element` *to* `get_elements`; that method gives you the elements that are already *in* the `Vector`.

Comment: Since `get_elements` belongs to the `Vector` class you are using it on a Vector and it will gives you the elements that are defined at the top of your Vector class `(self.elements)`

Comment: `get_elements` only takes the `self` argument, which is the instance of the class and is passed implicitly by invoke that method on an instance, `obj.get_elements()`. It's not clear from the code you've posted how these classes interact. Presumably, the `vector.elements` dict is a dict of `Element` instances, but it's not obvious how that would be assigned.

Comment: Thanks, the multiple element naming convention is what confused me.

Comment: Rest of code here: https://github.com/richandersn/chartshare/blob/master/Chartshare.py

Answer (score 0):

Vector's `get_elements()` doesn't take any arguments. Well, technically it does. It takes `self`. `self` is syntactic sugar that lets you do this:

```py
vec = Vector()
vec.get_elements()
```

It's equivalent to this:

```py
vec = Vector()
Vector.get_elements(vec)
```

Since `get_elements()` doesn't take any arguments, you can't pass `a` to it. Skimming the code, I don't see a `set_elements()` analog. This means you'll have to modify the vector's element's dictionary directly.

```py
vec = Vector()
vec.elements[a] = ...
print(vec.get_elements())  # >>> [a,...]
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, there is no place in this code where you are assigning `self.elements` with any input from a function. You are only initialising it or obtaining values

Also note that the `.get_elements()` function doesn't have any arguments (only self, that is the object where you are calling it in), so of course it won't work.

Unless you can do something such as the following, we would need more code to understand how to manipulate and connect these two objects.

```
element_obj = Element()
vector_obj = Vector()

position = 4
vector_obj.elements[4] = element_obj
```

I got to this answer with the following: as I can see, the elements property in the Vector class is a dictonary, that when you call `vector_obj.get_elements()` is casted to an array using the start and end parameters as delimiters.

Unless there is something else missing, this would be the only way I could think out of adding the an element into a vector object. Otheriwse, we would need some more code or context to understand how these classes behave with each other!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! Definitely adds more clarity. Below is the rest of the code.

https://github.com/richandersn/chartshare/blob/master/Chartshare.py